# Catch exception "PlayerInteractEvent" and checking location exist || Minecraft Plugin Spigot Bukkit

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I have a question.
I have a minecraft server plugin in which I am trying to use  which does not exist.

I am getting the following error:

> Could not pass event PlayerInteractEvent to XXX
> org.bukkit.event.EventException: null
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:319) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:70) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:589) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:576) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:483) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_16_R2.event.CraftEventFactory.callPlayerInteractEvent(CraftEventFactory.java:450) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerInteractManager.a(PlayerInteractManager.java:148) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:1219) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(SourceFile:40) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PacketPlayInBlockDig.a(SourceFile:10) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.PlayerConnectionUtils.lambda$0(PlayerConnectionUtils.java:19) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.TickTask.run(SourceFile:18) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeTask(SourceFile:144) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandlerReentrant.executeTask(SourceFile:23) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.executeNext(SourceFile:118) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.ba(MinecraftServer.java:941) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.executeNext(MinecraftServer.java:934) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.IAsyncTaskHandler.awaitTasks(SourceFile:127) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.sleepForTick(MinecraftServer.java:918) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.w(MinecraftServer.java:850) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_16_R2.MinecraftServer.lambda$0(MinecraftServer.java:164) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) [?:?]
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.bukkit.Location.getBlockZ()" because "this.secondLocation" is null
> at XXX.PlayerInteractEventListener.onPlayerUse(PlayerInteractEventListener.java:128) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[?:?]
> at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[?:?]
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:315) ~[spigot-1.16.3.jar:git-Spigot-57bbdd8-b8dd5ec]
> ... 21 more

Is there a list of exceptions for spigot?

Which exception in this case should I catch using try and catch?

Can anyone suggest any other way of checking if a given location exists?

Comment: Can you add the code PlayerInteractEventListener? you probably need something like `if (this.secondLocation == null) {...} else {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried verifying if the location is null?

```
if (location != null){
   // Do your thing
}
```

Comment: Hi, this is a useful, but in my case I have a location but not coordinates, the error I get occurs when I try take a coordinate by: 'variable= location.getBlockX();' from an object that does not have them defined.
(In the next step i increment this variable and set location X by this value.)

I do not know how to make a check at this stage, so I was thinking about using an try and catch exception .

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (secondLocation != null) {
    int someVar = secondLocation.getBlockZ();
}
```

If you want to catch exception you can use this:

```
try {
    int someVar = secondLocation.getBlockZ();
} catch (NullPointerException) {
    // Handle exception
}
```